# How can I tell what gear is appropriate to shoot architecture and street while travelling?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, travel, street-photography, architecture

I'm a beginner photographer and I'm going to Japan soon. I have a Canon Rebel T8i and the 18-55mm lens that came with it. I want to take pictures of the architecture and some street photography too.

I'm not sure if my 18-55 kit lens is appropriate or what would make for a better suited lens if it isn't. What features, like focal lengths or max. aperture, should I be considering for this type of shooting? Or is there some non-lens gear, like a tripod or filters, I should be thinking of instead of a new lens?

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers. You can make street photos will 10mm lens and with 200mm lens. Same is true about architecture. So what lens is about personal preferences.

Comment: It would need Canon experts to know if such is available for that camera, but my Nikon walkabout lens is an 18-300mm. Saves having to think about what to carry ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin, for Canon there is 18-135 EF-S, which is fine (for me). There is also 18-200. But by my experience on trips I rarely use >120mm (full frame)

Comment: If you are in architecture  you may need something shorter than than 18mm and Canon has not very expensive 10-18mm f/4.5-5.6 IS STM wide angle zoom that would be a good complement to your 18-55mm. For travel, it has the advantage of being fairly light.

Comment: @Nate, do you use your camera much at the moment? What shortcomings do you notice? Put that into words, and it makes answering your question so much easier.

Comment: the 18-55mm is a pretty basic lens, so sometimes I would like to be able to zoom in closer or get a wider shot, but I don't think I can get a lens that does both.

Comment: @nate remember, you have an _interchangeable_ lens camera for a reason - consider the possibility of using more than one lens. Maybe something like a 10-18mm lens could offer you a different perspective. For architecture and street photography, I think it might be less interesting to go for something longer than you already have.

Answer (score 3):

Your question can not be answered objectively.

Yes, there are some lenses specialized in architectonic photography to eliminate perspective distortions. But you are not working for an architectural magazine. Yes, there can be lenses more suitable for some users. But that needs to be defined by the user.

So, instead of giving you a lens opinion, a tip I can give you is:

**Be a tourist in your own hometown for a day. Take your camera and capture everything you can in your hometown to show it to the world.** And I mean all day.

If your hometown is really, and I mean, really small (or insecure) go to a nearby city.

Take some photos during the day, some during the afternoon, and some at night. That is the only way **you** will find the limitations of your current gear, and then, plan a new purchase. Probably night photography will be interesting in Japan because of all the neon lights and the safety of walking at late hours.

The only difference could be the height or dimension of the buildings. You probably have no skyscrapers in your town, but **how you use your camera is what matters**.

Also, carry your cellphone and take some photos with it.

What is important intitially is not the lens, it is What you want to see and capture with our camera.

Then and only then, you plan to get a new lens to facilitate your work.